# Import Delphi dll in vba

Tags: vba, delphi, dllimport

For a project, I need to import a DLL made in Delphi and call some functions.
However, nobody in the projectteam knows how to get this done. Our company supervisor made a program in C++ to open the DLL and call the functions, but he has not the experience in VBA.

Our project is to call the functions and pass some parameters from an excel worksheet to a program (Gas turbine Simulation Project). Our first question is: How do we load a Delphi dll in VBA? I read about the function dllimport, but still i don't know how to use this function.

For example, within the dll there is a function: d4868activateLog
The code in Delphi is as followed:

```
function activateLog (const filename: PAnsiChar):Integer;
```

How do we call this function?

Comment: I think your question will soon be closed for showing no [effort](http://bit.ly/ZcYEWW) to solve your problem.

Comment: I searched a lot on google, but without any result. As I said, there were some sites with dllimport, but this function is nowhere explained. I know the basics of VBA, I know how to Google, but how to import a dll file in vba is not explained well anywhere.

Comment: google "Access DLL in VBA", click "I'm feeling lucky" top result is [How to: Access DLLs in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687915%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: @Volksdansmatt On my computer the first(!!!) and third google result shows exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot call that function from VBA since it uses the `register` calling convention. VBA can only import `stdcall` functions.

You could change the Delphi code to:

```
function d4868activateLog(const filename: PAnsiChar): Integer; stdcall;
```

And then in the VBA you would write:

```
Private Declare Function d4868activateLog Lib "mydll.dll" (ByVal filename As String) As Long
```